# Template code behaves different the counter part

Tags: c++, templates

In my main.cpp,I tried to add element into tree using operator overload.
While in the original non-operator-overloading version,it works out to add element into
the tree,in this version,it fails out adding even 40,the second element into the tree 
structure which makes me very confused.I use double pointer to avoid pass by copy in c++ 
which should have worked nicely as before.Please help me to find out the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Tree.hpp"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Tree<TreeNode> tree;
    tree + 50 + 40 + 20 + 45 + 10 + 25;
    cout << tree.search(40)->data << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
Tree<T>& Tree<T>::operator+(int data) {
    insertNode(&root, data, nullptr);
    return *this;
}
```

```
template<typename T>
int Tree<T>::insertNode(T **start,int data,T* ancester){
    if((*start)==nullptr){
        *start=new T(data);
        (*start)->ancester=ancester;
        return 0;
    }
    if(data>(*start)->data){
        insertNode(&(*start)->LeftChild,data,*start);
    }
    if(data<(*start)->data)
        insertNode(&(*start)->RightChild,data,*start);
}
```

Here is the problem tree and functioning tree:

1. [problematic operator overloading tree](https://github.com/alstroemeria5/problem)
2. [functioning non-operator overloading tree](https://github.com/alstroemeria5/functioning_tree)

Comment: @arnes The compiler isn't allowed to change observable behavior of the program. It violates the as-if rule.

Comment: regardless of why your code doesn't work. This strike me as a "it's not because you could that you should" situation. Having a `operator+()` that behaves the way `operator+=()` normally does seems like a recipe for surprise and disaster.

Comment: @arnes In terms of associativity, yes.

Comment: @Frank,I got your advice.I will change my habit.But question is that when it was not operator-overloading,it worked.But now the tree just can't garble the element?As for L.F,I don't know what you  mean,Could you explain more thoroughly?

Comment: Going through the operator yields the exact same code as just calling InsertNode in sequence: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NbKN5D. There's probably something you aren't telling us here.

Comment: Try executing tree = tree+(40); only to test your code. Also check the operator + and operator += implementation.

Comment: May be the `tree.search` is failing?

Comment: @L.F. Ok im deleting my comments could you share a link for me to read ?

Comment: functional tree:https://github.com/alstroemeria5/functioning_tree

Comment: problem tree:https://github.com/alstroemeria5/problem

Comment: @arnes: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: I used debugger.I am pretty sure 40 was not added to the tree.